# Is there a way to group labels in Qlik Sense?

Tags: sql, qliksense

So I have data, and I want to count the labels:

```
Attribute            Labels
A                    Man, kind
B                    Girl, kind
C                    Man, bad
D                    Man
E                    Girl
```

I already put the data in Qlik Sense and created a pie chart based on labels, resulting in : `Man, kind = 1; girl ,kind = 1; man, bad = 1; man = 1; girl = 1`

But it isn't the expected result I want. The expected result I want is: `Man = 3 , girl = 2, kind =2 , bad = 2`. After that I will create a pie chart from the result.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [SubField](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/StringFunctions/SubField.htm) to split Labels per delimiter. You can also add 1 as `#number` so then is easier do just `SUM(#number)` in any chart.

You haven't included your code so I tested solution using `INLINE load` with your data and it is working fine.

```
[table]:
LOAD
    Attribute,
    SubField(Labels,', ') as Labels,
    1 as #number;
LOAD * INLINE [
    Attribute,     Labels
    A,             "Man, kind"
    B,             "Girl, kind"
    C,             "Man, bad"
    D,             "Man"
    E,             "Girl"
];
```

result:

[image]

Comment: sorry , just get back to work , i will test the code